# PHP how to obtain starting date of 1st week of november?

Tags: php

EDIT:

I have the following strings: "1-11-2013" and "2-9-2013". "1-11-2013" is read "1st week of november 2013", "2-9-2013" to be read "2nd week of september 2013".

So having those two strings, how do you get the start and end date of the weeks they represent? (Assuming the week starts on Monday)

Comment: You mean November 1st?

Comment: By "first week", do you mean `Oct/27 - Nov/2`, `Oct/28 - Nov/3`, or `Nov/1 - Nov/7`?

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first. A query for, say `php calculate start end week` will give you everything you need. Even a search for `PHP how to obtain starting date of 1st week of november?` turns up a correct solution in the top 10 results

Comment: Der Flatulator: November 1st may or may not be the 1st week of the month

Comment: Do you mean the first /full/ week of November? For instance, the first Monday in November?

Comment: I'm going to say, it's rather boneheaded to have these week-ids in a format that looks just like a legitimate date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this:

```
echo date('F jS, Y', strtotime('next Monday 2013-10-31'));
```

Bit of a cheat. Got it from this very useful page on the PHP site:

http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.relative.php

Very useful page. Cheers.

Not sure if that was the whole answer.

For the Monday of the week a given date (e.g. '1-11-2013') falls in try this:

```
echo date('F jS, Y', strtotime('next Monday', strtotime('1-11-2013 -7 days')));
```

Cheers.

Comment: How do you then, find the 4th full week of September 2013?

Comment: Using my 2nd code  line above. Assuming '1-9-2013 -1 days' gives you the last day in August - so with 'next Monday' gives first full week. Then 2nd full week uses '1-9-2013 +6 days', 3rd uses '1-9-2013 +13 days' and 4th uses '1-9-2013 +20 days'.

Comment: of course knowing this it follows that 4th full week is always strtotime('next Monday 21-9-2013') - and so for any maonth.

Answer (score 0):

Using PHP's [DateTime](http://php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php) class:

```
$date = new DateTime("2013-11-01");
echo $date->modify('first monday')->format('Y-m-d');
```